# post on facebook wall always show login page .. problem android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm using graph api from youtube , and i am facing some trouble .

I can send a msg to the wall , it works fine . The problem is that every time ,  it shows the login page and the user have to click at the ok button to send it. I'd like to send it without showing that page  , it should only shows at the first time . I store the token using
shared preferences  , but if i dont call the method facebook.autorize , which shows the login page ,  before trying to send the video , it does not work .

Am i doing it wrong ? thanks for any help .

My code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_lay);

    init();

    acessToken = loadAccessToken();
    Log.i("teste","Acesstoken depois do load : " + acessToken);

    if(acessToken == null || acessToken.equals("")){
        login();
    }else{
        Log.i("teste","Session valid com token salva ? " + mFacebook.isSessionValid());
        sendVideo();
    }


}

private void init(){
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    videoUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUrl");
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(APPLICATION_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private void login(){
    mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream","offline_access"},new AuthorizeListener());

}

public void postOnWall(String msg) {
  Log.i("teste", "Testing graph API wall post");
   try {
          Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
          parameters.putString("message", AUTO_MSG);
          parameters.putString("link", msg);
          mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
          "POST");

   } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

private void storeToken(String token){
    Log.i("teste","storeToken: " + token);
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(ACESS_TOKEN, token);
    editor.commit();
}

private String loadAccessToken() {
    String token = preferences.getString(ACESS_TOKEN, null);
    if (token != null && !token.equals("")  ) {
        return token;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private void sendVideo(){
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(FacebookView.this, "Sending","Enviando video ...");
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            postOnWall(videoUrl);
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        };
    }.start();
}

class AuthorizeListener implements DialogListener{

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.i("teste","Logou candelado!");
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.i("teste","Logou com sucesso!");
        Log.i("teste", "AcessToken : " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("teste", "AcessToken expires : " + mFacebook.getAccessExpires());
        Log.i("teste", "Session valid : " + mFacebook.isSessionValid());

        storeToken(mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        sendVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.i("teste","Erro ao logar: " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        Log.i("teste","FacebookError ao logar: " + e.getMessage());
        Log.i("teste","FacebookError ao logar Causa: " + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();            
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already find the answer . Just have to set the token on the facebook object .

acessToken = loadAccessToken();
    Log.i("teste","Acesstoken depois do load : " + acessToken);

```
if(acessToken == null || acessToken.equals("")){
    login();
}else{
   mFacebook.setAccessToken(acessToken); 
   Log.i("teste","Session valid com token salva ? " + mFacebook.isSessionValid());
   sendVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.greatup;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("208086425868080");

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },new DialogListener() {
//            
//          public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}
//
//            
//            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
//
//            
//            public void onError(DialogError e) {}
//
//            public void onCancel() {}
//        });

        facebook.dialog(this,"feed",

                  new DialogListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

                       @Override
                       public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                       @Override
                       public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                       @Override
                       public void onCancel() {}
                  }
            );




    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```